# gradle merge configurations.testRuntime with configurations.testCompile in copy

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'd like to copy some of my dependencies (retrieved from maven) to specific location in my `build.gradle` file.

If I iterate only testRuntime it works OK. My code is:

```
dependencies {
  testRuntime 'p6spy:p6spy:2.+'
  testRuntime 'com.h2database:h2:1+'
}

task foo {
    copy {
        from configurations.testRuntime.findAll { it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/p6spy/") || it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/h2/") }
        into "outputdir"
    }
}
```

however I'd like to go for `testCompile` rather than `testRuntime` in case of `h2` dependency. So I tried:

```
dependencies {
  testRuntime 'p6spy:p6spy:2.+'
  testCompile 'com.h2database:h2:1+'
}

task foo {
    copy {
        from [ configurations.testRuntime, configurations.testCompile ].flatten().findAll { it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/p6spy/") || it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/h2/") }
        into "outputdir"
    }
}
```

However here I get error:

```
No such property: from for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecWrapper_Decorated
```

I guess trouble is in my merging of the 2 lists here. Still can't figure out the right way.

Comment: Try wrapping it in parens... `from( [ configurations.testRuntime, configurations.testCompile ].flatten().findAll { it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/p6spy/") || it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/h2/") } )` The parser might be trying to access an element of a property called from...

Comment: @tim_yates: well, that solved the earlier exception, but now I have new one: `Could not find method getAbsolutePath() for arguments [] on configuration ':testRuntime'`, so it sounds like `flatten()` breaks things here

Comment: Maybe try: `from( [ configurations.testRuntime, configurations.testCompile ].collectMany { it.findAll { it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/p6spy/") || it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/h2/") } } )`

Comment: @tim_yates: that works, thanks! in the meantime I tested: `from configurations.testRuntime.plus(configurations.testCompile).findAll { it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/p6spy/") || it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/h2/") }`, still I guess that could cause `configurations.testRuntime` to be modified, that I need to prevent. So please post it as an answer, I'll accept it afterwards.

Comment: Actually, your way is more understandable ;-)  And as you're just adding two lists, neither list should be altered by the call `configurations.testRuntime.plus(configurations.testCompile)` is the same as `(configurations.testRuntime + configurations.testCompile)`.  I'd undelete your answer, and I'll vote it up :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will copy the files on every build invocation, even if the `foo` task isn't invoked. Here is a correct solution:

```
task foo(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.testRuntime // includes configurations.testCompile  
    into "outputdir"
    include "**/p6spy/**" 
    include "**/h2/**"  
}
```

Comment: thanks for clarification, and idea behind filtering? I have many more dependencies on these scopes, so how can I filter to these 2 only?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show one way of filtering.

Answer (score 1):

well, found solution myself, documenting it:

```
dependencies {
  testRuntime 'p6spy:p6spy:2.+'
  testCompile 'com.h2database:h2:1+'
}

task foo {
    copy {
        from configurations.testRuntime.plus(configurations.testCompile).findAll { it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/p6spy/") || it.getAbsolutePath().contains("/h2/") }
        into "outputdir"
    }
}
```